# Comparing values of 2 dictionaries

Tags: dictionary, comparison

Can anyone advice how I could compare values of 2 dictionaries. For example:

```
A = {'John': [(300, 5000), (700, 750), (10, 300)], 'Mary': [(12, 300), (5678, 9000), (200, 657), (800, 7894)]}
B = {‘Jim’:[(500,1000),(600,1500),(900,2000)], ‘Mary’:[(13,250), (1000,6000), (222,600)]}
```

I would like to compare the 2 such that if the 'key' (in this case 'Mary') is present between A and B dictionaries and the first and second numbers in the 'values' of B dictionaries are within that of the 'values in A (i.e. (13,250) and (222,600) are between (12,300) and (200, 657) respectively. The return results will therefore be 'Mary': [(13,250), (222,600)]

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I did what I think you wanted and retrieved the results (13,250)
(222,600). So it looks like it is working. I made three classes one was the main class, another a Point Class, and another class that did the filling of the dictionaries and comparing. I didn't know how you made up your dictionaries. But I made it like so:

```
private Dictionary<String,Map<String,List<Point>>> first 
= new Hashtable<String,Map<String,List<Point>>>();
```

It is dictionary that takes in a String and a Map, which takes in a String and  a List, which takes in a Point Object. When I look at your snippet there; it just screamed Points. So I made a small class with x and y properties.

Next, one should make a method that will compare the values of the points like using less than and greater than:

Then in another method after you fill the Dictionary, then check the dictionary and loop through the size of the second list of the dictionary

```
int size =  second.get("B").get("Mary").size(); 
for(int i =0; i<size; i++){
//compare method that you just made
}
```

Then print out results

My Output: Mary:(13,250)(222,600)

If you need any help with code please reply.